# What does % (percent sign) do in Apache's httpd.conf?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Okay, I see the following example from http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html.  Does `%{` and `}` makes Apache interpret the string between these two deliminators as an Apache variable?  Where is this functionality documented?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^$
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^80$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)         http://www.example.com:%{SERVER_PORT}/$1 [L,R,NE]
```

Then, http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/configuring.html describes using shell variables as `${ENVVAR}`.  What is the difference?

Comment: Please provide comment if you downvote or close.

Comment: Thank you he or she that reversed the previous down vote.  While the answer might seem obvious to all that know, it doesn't seem to be readily given searching for a solution.  I thank you for advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `%{NAME_OF_VARIABLE}` syntax (not simply the `%` symbol) is simply mod_rewrite's mechanism for accessing one of a predefined list of *server variables* ([specific to mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/env.html#url-rewriting)). As documented for the [`RewriteCond` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond).

Without the enclosing `%{`..`}` then `NAME_OF_VARIABLE` is seen as a literal string.

To access *environment variables* in mod_rewrite you use the syntax: `%{ENV:variable}`. (The other syntax `${ENVVAR}` also appears to work here, however, there is a difference in behaviour if `ENVVAR` does not exist. If `ENVAR` does not exist then `${ENVVAR}` returns the literal string "${ENVAR}", whereas `%{ENV:ENVAR}` returns an empty string. There *might* also be a conflict if you are using rewrite maps in `RewriteCond` since a similar syntax is used. ie `${mapname:key|default}` - although I would think the `:` should make this unambiguous?)